# how to unit test on window object in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

calling a function from ts file.

```
this.userDataService.getUserInfo()
```

userDataService.ts

```
 getUserInfo() {
return this.windowService.nativeWindow.$abc?.abcProfile?.UserProfileClient.getUser();
```

}

now when I try to do unit testing getting error abcProfile undefined.

I have no clue how to mock window data also I'm new to unit testing and project itself.its a angular project integrated on AEM

Please help.TIA

Comment: share the code of your `nativeWindow` inside `windowService`. Basically you have to mock the service itself and test. Share your test case too.

Comment: $abc:
abcProfile:
UserProfileClient:
getEntitlements: ƒ ()
getProxies: ƒ ()
getUser: ƒ ()

This is how nativewindow looks like..

Comment: I haven't written testcase yet.. going through the unit test concept